# I can't figure out this seg fault even though I initialized everything. Almost identical code works fine in another program.

Tags: c, scanf

I have already initialized a struct "treeFarm" above and have properly initialized the functions. This is inside an "insert" function to insert the new node to a binary search tree.

```
struct treeFarm * new = malloc(sizeof(struct treeFarm));
char * typeOfTree = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
new->type = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
printf("Please enter the lot number: ");
scanf("%d",&new->lotNum);
printf("Please enter the number of trees: ");
scanf("%d",&new->numTrees);
printf("Please enter the age of the trees: ");
scanf("%d",&new->age);
printf("Please enter the type of trees: ");
scanf("%s", typeOfTree);//seg fault happens here
strcpy(new->type, typeOfTree);
```

Comment: Did you check whether `malloc()` returned `NULL`?

Comment: Always check the return value of `malloc()`, in case of a problem it will return `NULL`. Also, it doesn't make sense to `malloc()` a fixed size, just declare `type` as `char type[21]` for it to be a `20` characters string (in combination with `"%19s"` from the answer below of course). And check the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior. One more thing, don't use `sizeof(char)` since it has to be `1` as per the c standard.

Comment: Does this line not do that? new->type = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

Comment: @kaylum Do not use `calloc()` for that, if you are doing things right you should not need to force initialization of every byte, if you do so you will hide the fact that *SOMETHING IS WRONG!*.

Comment: As a side note, `new` is probably not the best name you could use for a dynamically allocated variable in c

Comment: @Leeor you are to nice.  `new` is a horrible variable name in every way.  I suggest using `tmp'.

Comment: @Hogan why not something like `farm`? It is a `struct treeFarm*` after all. `tmp` just tells me it's a temporary (is it though?)

Comment: @Hogan `tmp` is just as bad in every way, except C++ compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
scanf("%19s", typeOfTree);
```

If you read more than 19 characters plus `'\0'` into `typeOfTree` a segfault is possible, *Undefined Behavior* is guaranteed.